# The best way to increase day in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<date>
    <olddate date="09/11/2016"/>
</date>
```

What is the best way to increment the date by 5 days using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Please check if this helps - http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/c0002.html

Comment: If you're looking for an XSLT 1.0 solution, why do you tag your question as XSLT 2.0?